# Who came up with "mascara lights" on cars?

Tags: etymology, phrases, history, noun-phrases

*Mascara lights* are [LED daytime running lights or lamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_running_lamp), typically in a wavy or curved pattern:

This photo shows DRLs on an Audi A4-B8:

[image: From Wikipedia]

When and where did this term originate? Is it an Audi coinage?

Answer (score 1):

### Mascara lights

A quick search didn't find any use of the term by Audi themselves. The formal term for the Audi version is "[daytime running lamp (DRL, also daylight running lamp or daytime running light)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_running_lamp)", often using LEDs to save energy.

The following Google Web/Images searches only find make-up:

- mascara lights
- "mascara lights"
- "mascara lights" car

Anyway, it's early days and this found some relevant uses:

- "mascara lights" audi

Third result of the 19 from *[Audi Club (South Africa) › Technical Discussions › General › NEW AUDI B8 A4](http://www.audiclubsa.org.za/cgi-bin/yabb25/YaBB.pl?num=1226308718)*, Reply #11 - Nov 11th, 2008 at 12:16pm, pstevens:

> The design drew my attention, after mulling over buying an Audi for a few years the B8’s design is what clinched it for me, there are a few things I do not like about it such as the **“Mascara” lights** as my wife calls the led DRL’s, but that’s why I chose not to go with the Xenon lights, if the A4 had the same design as the A5 I would have opted for them.
> [End]

### Mascara LEDs

*Mascara LEDs* is also used. *[Jalopnik: "Honda Unveils Low-Emission OSM Roadster, Possible New Design Direction"](http://jalopnik.com/399014/honda-unveils-low+emission-osm-roadster-possible-new-design-direction?comment=6816098#comments)*, comment by YMMV, 22 July 2008:

> Scrap the idiotic Audi **"mascara" LEDs** on the headlights and you've got a nicely proportioned car — a very nice design for any car arriving between say 1995 and 2005. For 2010 or later, it's already old. 7/22/08 12:15pm

### Mascara lamps

Another variation is *mascara lamps*. Here's it applied to Saabs: *[Saab Cars – Trollhattan Saab: "Old vs New (again) – Saab 9-5"](http://www.trollhattansaab.net/archives/2008/11/old-vs-new-again-saab-9-5.html)*, posted on November 6, 2008 by swade ([archived](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20081208232621/http://www.trollhattansaab.net/archives/2008/11/old-vs-new-again-saab-9-5.html)):

> Today I polled you Saabists for your opinion on Saab’s old 9-3 SS tail lamps vs the new ‘**mascara’ tail lamps** used from 2008 onwards.
>
> Right now, the poll stands at 57% for the old 9-3 tail lamps and 43% for the new **mascara lamps**, which shows that if nothing else, it’s a divisive move. Personally, I’m still in the mascara column, but I’d probably be even more selective about the body color than I’d normally be if I were getting one.

### Mascara headlights

*Mascara headlights* is earlier, used in 2006: *[The Truth About Cars: "BMW 335i Review"](http://www.thetruthaboutcars.com/2006/09/bmw-335i/)* by Jay Shoemaker on September 11, 2006 ([archived](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20101030095126/http://www.thetruthaboutcars.com/2006/09/bmw-335i/)):

> Chris Bangle’s designs are still a shock to the system. I still cringe whenever one of the BMW's “flame surfaced” 7 Series hoves into view. I still shake my head when I catch a glimpse of a 5 Series’ **mascara headlights**.

(There's also a market for these on the [tat bazaar](http://www.ebay.com.au/sch/Vehicle-Parts-Accessories-/131090/i.html?_fln=1&_itemId=190519079776&_nkw=Car%20headlight%20Eyelashes).)